# php class not found when it is included

Tags: php

I have a class in php called "SEO_URL". At a point in that class I have this

```
$class_name = "cPath_SEO_URL";
return $class_name::href();
```

and I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'cPath_SEO_URL' not found in
...\includes\classes\seo.class.php on line 52
```

The thing is I have included the class on top of SEO_URL

```
include_once(/path/to/my/class);
class SEO_URL{

}
```

and I get that error.

However, when I hard-code the class on top of the class SEO_URL it works. So this works.

```
class cPath_SEO_URL{
    function cPath_SEO_URL(){}
    function href() { return "CPathHref"; }
}
class SEO_URL{
...
       $class_name = "cPath_SEO_URL";
       return $class_name::href(); 
...
}
```

and this doesn't

```
include_once(/path/to/my/class);
class SEO_URL{
...
       $class_name = "cPath_SEO_URL";
       return $class_name::href(); 
...
}
```

I am trying this in oscommerce.

Why is that?

Comment: Do you have PHP warnings turned off? PHP will throw an E_WARNING exception when it can't find your class file, this will usually be output to the browser but it may be disabled.

Comment: No offense, but my 90%-sure guess is the class file is not correct. You should use require_once instead of include_once so that an error when reading it(like wrong file name/insufficient access rights) causes a fatal php error instead of just a warning.

Comment: +1 for @phihag for saying you should use `require_once` rather than `include_once` where your program can't live without the included file. This will give you useful errors when the require fails rather than weird errors when you try to use the related functions.

Comment: I have PHP warnings on. My first thought was also that it wan't included. However, I've tried both include_once, require_once. I'm quite sure the file is being loaded because I change the filename on purpose and I get the error " failed to open stream: No such file.."

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, you won't believe what was the problem.

I am used to open and close php file like this

```
<?
   ...
?>
```

not

```
<?php

?>
```

and the class file was without the `<?php .. ?>` tag but the `<? ... ?>` tag. I guess the environment I am working in now wanted the `<?php` not the `<?` only.

It would load the class but it wouldn't interpret it as php.

Comment: Sometimes you change your hosting enviorement and this behaviour starts. It is the `short_open_tag` php configuration.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
$class_name = "cPath_SEO_URL";
$test = new $class_name();
return $test::href();
```

you're making a static call on an instance. That doesn't make sense.
Instead you'll want to do

```
$class_name = "cPath_SEO_URL";
return $class_name::href();
```

Comment: yes, that's something I'll see afterwards, the thing is that it can't find the class when it is included. However, when I hard-code the class in the same file it is ok. Do you have any idea why it won't find the class when it is included?