# First time using classes - class not found

Tags: php, class

So what I thought was going to be a simple 50 odd lines of code has grown into something quite a bit bigger than anything I've ever worked on before and I've decided to move my code into classes.

This is a first for me, so I'm not 100% on how the new structure is supposed to fit together...

So I've created a class called weather in `weather.php`:

```
class weather
{
    // various variables and functions like getWeather() go here
}
```

I'm referencing it in my index.php as follows:

```
require_once("weather.php");

// instantiate the weather class.
$w = new weather();

// get the weather by calling the getWeather() function
$weather = $w->getWeather();
```

Based on what I'm understanding about what I've seen on SO and other sites (been to the PHP manual too), this should work, however, I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'weather' not found in C:\usbwebserver\root\weather\index.php on line 4

Line 4 is where I declare the class in `$w`.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here, can someone explain it to me?

**EDIT**
Adding an echo to the top of `weather.php` before the class didn't seem to write anything to the browser, however, what is being written to the browser appears to be code that exists within the class...

Comment: where is the class file in relation to the file in which you call the weather class?

Comment: are index.php and weather.php in the same directory?

Comment: @GarethL yes. djjjuk - the files are both in the same directory.

Comment: It seems correct. Try to debug it by printing something at the top of "weather.php" before your weather class.

Comment: All seems correct. Make sure you correctly include weather class.

Comment: check your error reporting. require_once should fail if it cant find it.

Comment: Do a PHP lint check on weather.php

Comment: they must be or the error would be different.  It is not saying it can not find the file, but the class.

Comment: Have you got an opening PHP tag in your weather.php file?

Comment: are u overriding `__autoload()` ?

Comment: Any chance it's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993385/php-class-not-found-when-it-is-included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are missing the php opening tag in your `weather.php` file.

Comment: They're also missing in index.php, which is working - so we can probably assume that OP has simply stripped them from his posting here

Comment: @MarkBaker you are correct, sir

Comment: in this case, what you can do is try include "weather.php"; instead of require_once. however, it seems very odd.

Comment: In fact, you are correct @jancha. The opening tag was there, but incomplete... In my rush, I missed the "php" part of it...